# Firefox outline css property works different than Chrome

Tags: css, google-chrome, firefox, outline, descendant

I am working with css outline property, and I found that it is working differently between Chrome and Firefox if descendant elements are outside.

- in Chrome, outline is only for itself range, even though any descendant elements are outside of itself area.

[image: results in chrome: blue rectangle has an outline, descendant green rectangle has not]

- in Firefox, outline is all range including all descendant elements.
  [image: results in Firefox: Bounding box of both blue and green has the outline]

```html
<div style="
    margin: 100px;
    width:  100px;
    height:  100px;
    background: blue;
    outline: solid 1px red;
    position:  relative;">
  <div style="
        width: 100px;
        height: 100px;
        background:  green;
        position: absolute;
        left:  50px;
        top: 50px;">
  </div>
</div>
```

I want Firefox to get same outline effect than Chrome.

Of course i know about border or box-shadow, but i can't use border now for some other reason. Because sometimes div has radius border, in this time border or box-shadow is radius, but it should have rectangular outline, so we can't use border or box-shadow.

How can I do this?

Comment: This is a know [FF *bug**](https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=687311) reported... 7 years ago. (* Well [current specs](https://drafts.csswg.org/css-ui/#outline-props) say they let this to implementors, so is it really a bug?)

Comment: @Kaiido, thanks for your response, so the solution is box-shadow?

Comment: Well if it is viable for you, then yes, you can use box-shadow as a workaround. (but with no other style than `solid`...)

Comment: @Kaiido, thanks, but now i can't use box-shadow, Div can take radius border property. In this case, box-shadow is radius, but i want rectangular outline.

Answer (score 0):

try this add display:inline-table;

```html
<div style="
margin: 100px;
width:  100px;
height:  100px;
background: blue;
outline: solid 1px red;
position:  relative;
display: inline-table;">
    <div style="
    width: 100px;
    height: 100px;
    background:  green;
    position: absolute;
    left:  50px;
    top: 50px;">
    </div>
```

Comment: Thanks for your response, it looks working, but now i can't use display: inline-table property....

Comment: what is the problem with display: inline-table property ?

Comment: now i have inputed simple code for show, but actually div has some many contents inside, it should property display: block.

Answer (score 0):

try this code i replaced outline with border

```
<div style="
margin: 100px;
width:  100px;
height:  100px;
background: blue;
border: solid 1px red;
position:  relative;">
    <div style="
    width: 100px;
    height: 100px;
    background:  green;
    position: absolute;
    left:  50px;
    top: 50px;">
    </div>
</div>
```

here is the fiddle

https://jsfiddle.net/0pr1t07y/

Comment: Thanks for your response. i can't use border, because sometimes div has radius border, but it should have rectangular outline.

Comment: you can apply border-radius also

Comment: i mean our outline should be rectangle even though border radius set.

Comment: i updated my answer with small changes . see this fiddle https://jsfiddle.net/sLk4550q/13/

Comment: Thanks, but when parent div position is not 'relative', it does not happen.

Comment: ok, Finally see this it is very helpful to you i think  https://jsfiddle.net/8kzcrvc5/3/

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/166451/discussion-between-shaik-and-alex).

Comment: Thanks, but this happend when any descendant element is contained in parent div that set outline.